# Elasticsearch search data with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, elasticsearch

i want to search on the 'Index' and 'Type' that is input from the user through a html form. I'm new to both angular and Elasticsearch.

i tried using this code and binding the variables through ng-model

```
ExampleApp.controller('MatchController', function ($scope, client, esFactory) {
    function click($scope){
        $scope.index = '';
        $scope.type = '';
        $scope.key = '';

client.search({
index:  $scope.index ,
type: $scope.type ,
size: 50,
body: {
"query":
    {
        "match": {

            name:  $scope.key
        }   
    },
}
```

html code...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="index" id="index" /> <br><br>
<input type="text" ng-model="type" id="type" /><br><br>
<input type="text" ng-model="key" id="key" /><br><br>
<input type="button" value="search" onclick="click()">
```

Is it possible to do this??? if so how??

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a service to connect and query elasticsearch using your functions.

https://www.sitepoint.com/building-recipe-search-site-angular-elasticsearch/

The above link shows you how to create and run queries via elasticsearch and AngularJS. The service that I mentioned is written in the last block of code. I suggest you read the whole article though to give you a better understanding.

You're mostly on the right track except your whole client.search part needs to go into a service which you call, otherwise whenever the controller is called that will be called too which you don't want happening.